# Proxy setting for mobile network data connection

Tags: android, mobile, proxy

On android device, is there a way (by setting or code) to define the proxy settings for the mobile network data connection. I can see how to do it for Wifi but how about mobile data plan?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can define the proxy by standard android config in:
Settings->(More...)->Mobile networks->Access Point Names->(Select active list item)->
and here you can enter the Proxy and Port fields.

Also looking into a way to do it programmatically, will post findings or check later back to see if someone else solved it :)